# +- alignment argument in tabular

Tags: tables, arguments

I want the text in the column to be aligned by the `\pm` symbol from amssymb. I know there is a package called siunitx which allows for decimal alignment in tabular by using "S" as a column argument like so: `\begin{tabular}{|cSr|}` .
When you use the package: `\usepackage{siunitx}`

Is there an equivalent of this for the `\pm` sign? Perhaps using the same package or another one? The easy option for alignment is making two columns the first right adjusted with `r` and the `\pm` column on the right, left adjusted, but this is not what I am asking for.

Example:

```
\begin{tabular}{l|X|r}
    \toprule
    {Name} & {Value} & {Unit} \\
    \midrule
        Ab  & {$1500,0 \pm 0,5$}  &   Kg \\
        Cd  & {$4,9 \pm 0,1$}   &   s \\
        Ef  & {$209$ \pm 2$}    &   m \\
    \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
```

I simply want to know: is there, or is there not an argument "X" for the tabular environment that aligns the `\pm` signs, and if yes, what package do you need to use to be able to call it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `siunitx` package supports this:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx,booktabs}

\sisetup{
  separate-uncertainty,
  output-decimal-marker={,},
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{l S[table-format=4.1(1)] s}
\toprule
Name & {Value} & {Unit} \\
\midrule
Ab  & 1500,0 \pm 0,5  &  kg \\
Cd  & 4,9    \pm 0,1  &  s \\
Ef  & 209    \pm 2    &  m \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: What does the "table-format=4.1(1)" part mean? Is table 4.1 for +- separation or something?

Comment: @Vebjorn It means “four digits in the integral part, one digit in the decimal part and one significant digit for the uncertainty”.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the particulars, but at least in this case, one could use a TABstack:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs,tabularx,tabstackengine}
\begin{document} 
\begin{tabular}{l|c|r}
    \toprule
    {Name} & {Value} & {Unit} \\
    \midrule
        \Centerstack[l]{Ab \\ Cd\\ Ef} &
        \ensurestackMath{\alignCenterstack{
          1500,0 \pm& 0,5\\4,9 \pm& 0,1\\209 \pm& 2}} &
        \Centerstack[r]{Kg \\s \\ m}\\
    \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]